# Validating Forms with Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have a form with 4 dropdownlists whose autopostback property is set to true and each dropdown list gets populated based on the selection of the previous dropdownlist.
Ex. ddlCourseType gets populated after a selection is made in ddlCourseLevel and so on.

I need to validate every textbox and dropdownlist but am having a hard time with the dropdownlists because of its autopostback property.

It will be great if somebody could help me with the best way to validate this form or any tips or advice would be awesome. Thanks a lot. Below is the aspx file that has the jquery function for validating dropdowns and textboxes.

**Admin_Course_Edit.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="/JQuery_Plugins/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../JQuery_Plugins/timepicker/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#tbStartDate').datepicker({
                duration: '',
                showTime: true,
                constrainInput: false
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="BreadCrumbs" runat="server">
    <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server">
    </asp:SiteMapPath>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="rightNavigation" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //Function to Validate DatePicker
            $.validator.addMethod('isDate', function (value, element) {
                var isDate = false;
                try {
                    $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', value);
                    isDate = true;
                }
                catch (e) {

                }
                return isDate;
            });

            //Function to Validate DropDown Lists
            $.validator.addMethod('selectNone',
          function (value, element) {
              return this.optional(element) ||
                (value.indexOf("") == -1); //Leave it blank or enter the exact text in index 0
          }, "Please Select an Option");



            $("#form1").validate({
                // $("#tbStartDate").rules("add", {isDate: true} messages: {isDate: "Date to Validate is invalid."}

                rules: {
                    '<%=ddlCourseLevel.UniqueID %>': { selectNone: true },
                    '<%=tbStartDate.UniqueID %>': { required: true, isDate: true },
                    '<%=tbCourseName.UniqueID %>': { required: true, maxlength: 25 },
                    '<%=tbPointScale.UniqueID %>': { required: true, digits: true },
                    '<%=tbDescription.UniqueID %>': { maxlength: 50 }
                },
                messages: { '<%=tbStartDate.UniqueID %>': { isDate: "Please enter a Valid Date"} }


            });


            $("#imgBtn_A_save").click(function (evt) {


                // Validate the form and retain the result.
                var isValid = $("#form1").valid();

                // If the form didn't validate, prevent the
                //  form submission.
                if (!isValid)
                    evt.preventDefault();
            });

            $("#imgBtn_A_cancel").click(function () {
                $("#form1").validate().cancelSubmit = true;

            });
        });

        function HideLabel() {
            document.getElementById('<%= lblMessage.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
        }
        setTimeout("HideLabel();", 2000);

    </script>
    <div class="Admin_rightNavtop">
        <div class="title">
            <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" Text="Edit Course" runat="server" class="titleLbl" />
        </div>
        <p align="center">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Style="color: Red" /></p>
        <!-- START TABLE ADD FORM-->
        <table style="margin-left: 70px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblCourseLevel" Text="* Course Level :" runat="server" class="lblSize_largeGreen" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourseLevel" class="ddlSize_large_addEdit" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCourseLevel_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" OnDataBound="helperCourseLevel_Databound"
                        runat="server" />
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="CourseType" Text="* Course Type :" runat="server" class="lblSize_largeGreen" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourseType" runat="server" class="ddlSize_large_addEdit"
                        OnDataBound="helperCourseType_Databound" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCourseType_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true" />
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCourseName" Text="* Course Name :" runat="server" class="lblSize_largeGreen" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourseName" class="ddlSize_large_addEdit" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCourseName_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" OnDataBound="helperCourse_Databound"
                        runat="server" />
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCourseName2" Text="* New Name :" runat="server" class="lblSize_largeGreen" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbCourseName" class="tbSize_large_addEdit" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" Text="* Start Date :" runat="server" class="lblSize_largeGreen" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbStartDate" runat="server" class="tbSize_large_addEdit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblGraded" Text="* Grade Type :" runat="server" class="lblSize_largeGreen" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGradeType" runat="server" class="ddlSize_large_addEdit"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGradeType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem>---Select Grade Type---</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Point Scale</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Pass/Fail</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Attendance</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Not Graded</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPointScale" Text="* Point Scale :" runat="server" class="lblSize_largeGreen"
                        Visible="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbPointScale" runat="server" class="tbSize_large_addEdit" Visible="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" Text="Description :" runat="server" class="lblSize_largeGreen" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbDescription" runat="server" class="tbSize_large_addEdit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- End of Table ADD COURSE-->
    </div>
    <!-- End of rightNavTop-->
    <center>
        <div class="Admin_action">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn_A_save" ImageUrl="../Images/Save.png" OnClick="save_Click"
                runat="server" class="Admin_action_imgSize_small" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn_A_cancel" ImageUrl="../Images/Cancel.png" runat="server"
                class="Admin_action_imgSize_small" CausesValidation="false"    OnClick="cancel_Click" />
        </div>
    </center>
    <!-- End selection buttons-->
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onchange event to the control and return false if you think it's invalid to cancel the postback.

Personally, I'd want to do the whole shebang using jQuery and AJAX and cut out the nasty auto postback.

Comment: Hi Jeff,

I guess its better to use Jquery and Ajax as you mentioned. I cannot use Onchange because I would still require it to postback to populate the other dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

The validations for the dependent DDLs will also have to check their "parent" DDL.

```
DDL 1 - Must be selected
DDL 2 - If DDL 1 is selected must be selected.
DDL 3 - If DDL 2 is selected must be selected.
DDL 4 - If DDL 4 is selected must be selected.
```

Sorry I don't have time to write up the code, but hopefully this will be helpful.